# How to move from child layout to parent layout with losing data on parent layout? And How can I optimize my code?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development.
Following is the code to my android app called "My Fruit List" in which Main Activity shows chosen fruits in "Text Views" arranged in "Linear Layout (vertical orientation)" inside "Scroll Views" that are selected from the second layout by using the "ADD A FRUIT" button at the bottom of the current Main Layout. This program functions as expected but I have two questions:

1. My first question is that as I have made the Main Activity as the parent activity for the second layout that's working as a child activity. But when I move from child to parent using the left arrow at the top left all the data from Main Activity's Text Views are vanished. I have overridden onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance for keeping the main activity's data when screen's rotated but when I move from child to parent using the top left arrow it vanishes all the data present in those "Text Views". Why?
2. My second question is that how can I optimize my code means by making it more shorter and clearer?

Much Thanks!

MainActivity.java:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private Button button_addItem;
private TextView item1;
private TextView item2;
private TextView item3;
private TextView item4;
private TextView item5;
private TextView item6;
private TextView item7;
private TextView item8;
private TextView item9;
private TextView item10;

private static final int CHOSEN_FRUIT = 1;

//string keys for onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance
private static final String ITEM_1_KEY = "item1key";
private static final String ITEM_2_KEY = "item2key";
private static final String ITEM_3_KEY = "item3key";
private static final String ITEM_4_KEY = "item4key";
private static final String ITEM_5_KEY = "item5key";
private static final String ITEM_6_KEY = "item6key";
private static final String ITEM_7_KEY = "item7key";
private static final String ITEM_8_KEY = "item8key";
private static final String ITEM_9_KEY = "item9key";
private static final String ITEM_10_KEY = "item10key";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button_addItem = findViewById(R.id.button_addItem);
    item1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item1);
    item2 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item2);
    item3 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item3);
    item4 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item4);
    item5 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item5);
    item6 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item6);
    item7 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item7);
    item8 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item8);
    item9 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item9);
    item10 = findViewById(R.id.textView_item10);

    button_addItem.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AvailableItems.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOSEN_FRUIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CHOSEN_FRUIT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (item1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item1.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item2.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item3.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item4.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item5.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item5.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item6.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item6.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item7.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item7.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item8.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item8.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item9.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item9.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else if (item10.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
                item10.setText(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "List is full!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//               Log.d("TESTMESSAGE", "onActivityResult: " + data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(ITEM_1_KEY, item1.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_2_KEY, item2.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_3_KEY, item3.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_4_KEY, item4.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_5_KEY, item5.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_6_KEY, item6.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_7_KEY, item7.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_8_KEY, item8.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_9_KEY, item9.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(ITEM_10_KEY, item10.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    item1.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_1_KEY).toString());
    item2.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_2_KEY).toString());
    item3.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_3_KEY).toString());
    item4.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_4_KEY).toString());
    item5.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_5_KEY).toString());
    item6.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_6_KEY).toString());
    item7.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_7_KEY).toString());
    item8.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_8_KEY).toString());
    item9.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_9_KEY).toString());
    item10.setText(savedInstanceState.get(ITEM_10_KEY).toString());

}}
```

AvailableItems (SecondActivity):

```
package com.xafak.fruitshoppinglist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AvailableItems extends AppCompatActivity { 

private Button bananaImage;
private Button grapeImage;
private Button appleImage;
private Button watermelonImage;
private Button pineappleImage;
private Button avocadoImage;
private Button cherryImage;
private Button cirtusImage;
private Button strawberryImage;
private Button pomegranateImage;

public static final String FRUIT_ID = "fruit_id";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_available_items);

    bananaImage = findViewById(R.id.bananas);
    grapeImage = findViewById(R.id.grapes);
    appleImage = findViewById(R.id.apple);
    watermelonImage = findViewById(R.id.watermelon);
    pineappleImage = findViewById(R.id.pineapple);
    avocadoImage = findViewById(R.id.avocado);
    cherryImage = findViewById(R.id.cherry);
    cirtusImage = findViewById(R.id.citrus);
    strawberryImage = findViewById(R.id.strawberry);
    pomegranateImage = findViewById(R.id.pomegranate);

}


public void addItemToList(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bananas:
            configureIntent("Bananas");
            break;
        case R.id.grapes:
            configureIntent("Grapes");
            break;
        case R.id.apple:
            configureIntent("Apple");
            break;
        case R.id.watermelon:
            configureIntent("Watermelon");
            break;
        case R.id.pineapple:
            configureIntent("Pineapple");
            break;
        case R.id.avocado:
            configureIntent("Avocado");
            break;
        case R.id.cherry:
            configureIntent("Cherry");
            break;
        case R.id.citrus:
            configureIntent("Citrus");
            break;
        case R.id.strawberry:
            configureIntent("Strawberry");
            break;
        case R.id.pomegranate:
            configureIntent("Pomegranate");
            break;
        default:
    }
}

public void configureIntent(String fruitName) {

    Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
    replyIntent.putExtra(FRUIT_ID, fruitName);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
    finish();
} }
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xafak.fruitshoppinglist">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AvailableItems"
            android:label="Available Fruits"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|clip_horizontal|center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_addItem"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_item10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textSize="45sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_addItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/select_fruit"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shoppingcart" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_available_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AvailableItems">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.39"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bananas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/bananas"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/apple"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/apple"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/avocado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/avocado"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cherry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/cherry"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/citrus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/citrus"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/grapes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/grapes"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pineapple"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/pineapple"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pomegranate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/pomegranate"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/strawberry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/strawberry"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/watermelon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="addItemToList"
            android:text="@string/watermelon"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="583dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fruit_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fruitmarket" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Need for onSaveInstanceState or onRestoreState.

use an arraylist, which holds the Strings for your TextViews.

```
private ArrayList<String> arraylist = ArrayList<String>();
```

This will make sure, that at the beginning you have an empty arraylist.

In OnActivityResult you add the new received String to the arraylist.

```
 if (requestCode == CHOSEN_FRUIT) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        arraylist.add(data.getStringExtra(AvailableItems.FRUIT_ID));
     }
 }
```

finally you use the Strings in onResume to fill your TextViews with data.

```
if(arraylist.size==1){
TextView1.setText(arraylist[0];
}
if(arraylist.size==2){
TextView2.setText(arraylist[1];
}
.
.
.
```

Even when your device is rotated the data inside your ArrayList should be kept and the TextViews gets filled with data in onResume.

This is not the most elegant way to make a list, as it does not increase dynamically in size, but for a dynamic increase in size you could implement a recyclerview for example.

Comment: But this does not get called, when you use the back button. For your case you could use a viewmodel to hold the data

Comment: I now have used the bundle to hold the data, I have initialized this bundle with default values in onCreate() and have assigned the values to TextViews in onResume(). But I am not understanding that how can I pass a bundle to onActivityResult() as it's parameters include onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)?

Comment: Your onActivityResult has data and you can replace data in your bündle with These data. The onResume will be called after onActivityResult and the new values you received in OnActivityResult will be used  as values for your TextViews.

Comment: I cannot replace data with bundle as it again asks for data (INTENT) in super method's parameters.

Comment: Now I've created a method called updateBundle() that updates the bundle by taking the values present in these TextViews. This method is called in onCreate() for initializing it bundle, then this bundle is called in onActivityResult after the TextViews get new values for the second activity so that those values are again stored in the bundle.

Comment: Everthing works fine until the device is rotated or when the back button in second activity is used which calls the onCreate() which further calls updateBundle() and all of a sudden all the TextViews are empty again.

Comment: i slowly start to understand what you are trying to do, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Even though ArrayList is declared outside of all the method means just after the class MainActivity begins. Still after applying the changes as you directed in your most recent answer, I am afraid to say that when the device is rotated ArrayList's becomes empty with arrayList.size() equal to zero, I have checked it by using logd in onCreate() method.